# Disable submission of contact form 7 on pressing enter

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a multi step contact form in the same url. The problem is, that when someone presses <kbd>enter</kbd> before achieving all steps it sends the form. How can I modify the contact form to deactivate the possibility of sending a form by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following lines to disable enter on a specific form.

```
function sally_disable_enter_contact_7( ) {
?>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
         
        // Only run this snippet on the form ID 1114
        jQuery( '#wpcf7-f1114-p1110-o1' ).on( 'keypress keydown keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.which== 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
         
    </script>
 
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'sally_disable_enter_contact_7', 30 );
```

add this code to `functions.php`.

replace the `wpcf7-f1114-p1110-o1` with the ID of your form.

- You may need to check the ID by using view-source or inspect